# Angular Component part of two declarations

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I created a small component which I want to use in some of the pages but I seem to have some problems when including it in more than one lazy load page.

add.button.component.ts

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'add-button',
  template: `
  <ion-buttons end>
    <button ion-button icon-only (click)="navToAdd()">
      <ion-icon name="md-add-circle"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>`
})

export class AddButton {
  visible: boolean = true;

  @Output() navigate: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  navToAdd() {
    this.navigate.emit(null)
  }
}
```

app.modules.ts

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { MyApp } from './app.component';
    import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
    import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

users.module.ts - Just like `users.module.ts` there are other page modules where I want to use the component just like i use it in `users.module.ts` below

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { UsersPage } from './users';
import { AddButton } from '../../components/add-button.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UsersPage,
    AddButton
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(UsersPage),
  ],
})
export class UsersPageModule { }
```

Comment: I would create a Common-Module for those Components and include the Module in both other modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AddButton should probably be on a [Shared module](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#shared-feature-module) and then you would be able to use it in multiple places by importing the module

Comment: Ok ... Seems simple enough to create a shared module. I don't know where to include it. Do I include the shared module in all page modules? Like `users.module.ts`, `events.module.ts`? What should `users.module.ts` look like?

Answer (score 1):

add your `AddButton` component into `exports` array of `users.module.ts` so you can use it in other modules where `UsersModule` is imported

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { UsersPage } from './users';
import { AddButton } from '../../components/add-button.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UsersPage,
    AddButton
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(UsersPage),
  ],
  exports: [
    AddButton
  ]
})
export class UsersPageModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create the component with the `ionic cli` with ionic **g component AddButton** it will automatically create a ComponentsModule and your new component in that module.

And to use this component in the other modules you just have to import that module in the modules that you need.

Also in your ComponentModule you should add `imports: [IonicModule]` in order to be able to use the Ionic Components like **ion-buttons**

Answer (score 0):

If you think ButtonComponent doesn't fit to be in Shared Module, Make a Individual module for `AddButton`. Now this new module should declare and export the `AddButtonComponent`. You should import this new module in whichever child module you want it to be used for. This should not cause any problem. This will also save you from loading all Shared component just for sake of getting `AddComponent` working.

> It's a best practice to create another module for the component if it is being used at multiple places/modules.